# Using Graphics to load an image and rotate it into a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi

I am trying to use the graphics object to load an image in and then rotate it (either portrait or landscape) and then display it in a panel (not a picture box).

How would I load the graphics in the panel? Also what would be the simplest way to do a landscape or portrait rotation on the graphics object?

GDI must be used to rotate and work with the image, I need a way to get the Graphics object into the panel.

Comment: Gtk-Sharp? Cairo? XWT? OpenGL? WebkitSharp? You need a few more tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Paint` event of the Panel:

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int angle = 90;
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Image i = new Bitmap(@"C:\Jellyfish.jpg");
        g.TranslateTransform((float)i.Width / 2, (float)i.Height / 2);
        g.RotateTransform(angle);
        g.TranslateTransform(-(float)i.Width / 2, -(float)i.Height / 2);
        g.DrawImage(i, new Point(0,0));

    }
```

Comment: Isn't this cropping the original image when rotated?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about a panel and it's C#, I will guess you are referring to WinForms.

You can rotate any `Image` instance using the `RotateFlip` method, and you can use an `Image` as the `BackgroundImage` of your panel. A working example:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"D:\word.png");
bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
Form form = new Form() { Height = 400, Width = 600 };
Panel p = new Panel() { Height = 400, Width = 600, Left = 0, Top = 0};
form.Controls.Add(p);
p.BackgroundImage = bitmap;
form.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks, although it is important that I use GDI to do the work with the image :)

Comment: Do you mean you can't use the RotateFlip method for some reason ?

Comment: No I am currently using the method you are suggesting but it is a requirement that I use GDI to manipulate the image. After it has been rotated (either Portrait or Landscape) it needs to be loaded into a panel.

GDI instead of RotateFlip method I mean to say.